# What causes a door to appear open?

Tags: fez

When playing through Fez there are many unlocked doors that you need only press "up" on to open.  I have noticed as I pass some doors they already appear open, apparently after I have visited that "room".  Does the door appear open forever after the first time I enter the room, or is the "appearing open" tied to something else like getting 100% in that room?  Once the door appears open, will it continue to stay open forever?  I ask mainly because this could be a very useful way of determining where I had already visited (all the doors start to get confusing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**After you open a door for the first time, it will always appear "open" (black).**

When you unlock locked doors, the first ↑ will just unlock the door. They'll show as black even before you enter.

It isn't related to progress. Yes, it is somewhat confusing.